# Clear particular value in a textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox which contains values as in the following pattern

```
N+,WINDOWS 8.1
```

I want to remove `WINDOWS 8.1` from the textbox.How can I do that using Jquery?.

Comment: pls show what you have tried

Comment: $("input[type='text']).val().replace("WINDOWS 8.1","");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#whateverTextboxId").val(function(){

   $(this).val().replace("WINDOWS 8.1", "");

});
```

Shouldn't this be a straight forward way.